# Contourf plot not showing enough detail

Tags: matlab, plot

In the below MATLAB code, I generate a surface plot and a contourf plot of the same data. The contourf plot does not show the same detail as the surface plot does. What options can I pass to the contourf plot so that I see the same/better detail?

Perhaps there is a different contour plot I can use? Otherwise, perhaps a different contrast for the surface plot?

The MWE code is given below.

[image]
[image]

```
%% Solve the fDNLS with PERIODIC boundary conditions. Time-evolution of fDNLS
% Problem is split into Re and Im parts. 

tic
warning('off','all')

%% Fixed parameters
eps=1;
a=1;
w = 1;
v = 1;
s = 1+a; 
h = 1;   
N = 50; % N+(N-1) = Grid
p = 2*N; % Total components of sol. vector

tspan = [0 30]; % Time domain
x = ((-N*h):(h):((N-1)*h))'; % Space domain

%% Real/Im matrix
operator_matrix = LRI_matrix_periodic(N,a);
e = eig(operator_matrix);
% Symplectic matrix
%J = zeros(2*p,2*p);
%J(1:p,p+1:2*p) = eye(p);
%J = J - J';

%% ODE Problem defined
F = @(t,z) eps*operator_matrix*z; %+ ((z.^2+(J*z).^2)).*(J*z); % Dynamics
jacobian = @(t,z) eps*operator_matrix; %+ 2*diag(z.*(J*z)) + J*diag(3*(z.*z) + (J*z).*(J*z)); % Jacobian




%% Initial condition
initial_condition = zeros(2*p,1);
ic_value = 1;
initial_condition(3*N) = ic_value;

%% Run ode23s
options = odeset('Jacobian', jacobian,'RelTol',1e-3,'AbsTol',1e-6); % Pass the Jacobian. Significant speed increase using this.
[tSol,YSol] = ode23s(F,tspan,initial_condition,options); % Solve the problem
Real_YSol = YSol(:,1:p);
Imaginary_YSol = YSol(:,p+1:end);

[row_size, col_size] = size(Real_YSol);
%% DLS Solution vector defined
qn = @(n,t) (1i)^(n) * besselj(n,2*t);

DLS_Sol = zeros(row_size,col_size);
DLS_Sol(1,:)=0;
DLS_Sol(1,49)=1;
for i = 2:row_size
    for j = 1:col_size
        DLS_Sol(i,j) = qn(j-(N + 1), tSol(i));
    end
    if i == 1
        DLS_Sol(i,51) = 1;
    end 
end


display(e)

figure
surf(x,tSol,Real_YSol.^2+Imaginary_YSol.^2,'EdgeColor','none')
colorbar;
xlabel("Space")
ylabel("Time")
title("Intensity: Linear regime, \alpha = "+a+", Initial condition u_0(0) = "+ic_value)
view([0,90])

%figure
%surf(x,tSol,DLS_Sol.^2,'EdgeColor','none')
%colorbar;
%xlabel("Space")
%ylabel("Time")
%title("DLS Intensity: Linear regime")
%view([0,90])


figure
contourf(x,tSol,Real_YSol.^2+Imaginary_YSol.^2,'EdgeColor','none')
colorbar;
xlabel("Space")
ylabel("Time")
title("Intensity: Linear regime, \alpha = "+a)
colorbar;

%figure
%amplitude=Real_YSol.^2+Imaginary_YSol.^2;
%[argvalue, argmax] = max(amplitude');
%plot(tSol,argmax-(N),'LineWidth',2)
%title("Position of intensity"),
%ylabel("ArgMax"), xlabel("time")
%axis padded

toc
function M = LRI_matrix_periodic(N,a)
p = 2*N;

%% Initialize the coefficient matrix for the LRI operator
M1 = zeros(p, p);
M2 = zeros(p, p);
M3 = zeros(p, p);
M4 = zeros(p, p);


%% Populate the first block matrix
for n = 1:p
    M1(n,n) = 0;
    for r = (n+1):p
        M1(n,r) = -1*imag(cnr(n-(N+1),r-(N+1),a,N));
        M1(r,n) = M1(n,r);
    end
end

%% Populate the second block matrix
for n = 1:p
    M2(n,n) = -2*zeta(1+a)*(1 - 1/(2*N)^(1+a));
    for r = (n+1):p
        M2(n,r) = real(cnr(n-(N+1),r-(N+1),a,N));
        M2(r,n) = M2(n,r);
    end
end

%% Populate the third block matrix
for n = 1:p
    M3(n,n) = 2*zeta(1+a)*(1 - 1/(2*N)^(1+a));
    for r = (n+1):p
        M3(n,r) = -1*real(cnr(n-(N+1),r-(N+1),a,N));
        M3(r,n) = M3(n,r);
    end
end

%% Populate the fourth block matrix
for n = 1:p
    M4(n,n) = 0;
    for r = (n+1):p
        M4(n,r) = -1*imag(cnr(n-(N+1),r-(N+1),a,N));
        M4(r,n) = M4(n,r);
    end
end

%% Coefficient matrix for the Long Range Interaction operator with periodic boundary conditions 
M = [M1 M2; M3 M4];
end
function off_diag = cnr(n,r,a,N)
    off_diag = 1/abs(n-r)^(1+a) + 1/(2*N).^(1+a) * (hurwitzZeta(1+a, (r-n)/(2*N)) + hurwitzZeta(1+a, -(r-n)/(2*N)) - abs((r-n)/(2*N)).^(-(1+a)) * (1 + exp(-1i * (1+a) * pi)));
end
```

Comment: Did you look at [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html)? The `levels` argument can be used to specify at which levels you want a contour. You probably want to have more at low levels than at high levels, a logarithmic spacing seems relevant (see `logspace`).

Comment: As a surface plot, I'd apply a logarithmic mapping to the height. This will put more of the different colors of the color map into the lower heights, and fewer into that one little high peak.

Comment: I had tried ``logspace(1,5)``, but this just yielded a white plot.

Comment: Well, your data is between 0 and 1, so creating logarithmically spaced values between 10 and 100000 is not going to be useful. You want to do `logspace(-5,0,10) or something like that, maybe. Play around with the values until you're satisfied. Read the docs to understand the meaning of the values: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logspace.html

Comment: I can't reproduce your plots because `LRI_matrix_periodic` is undefined. I suggest instead you post code to create a small matrix with similar properties to your actual data. Anything that would allow us to experiment with the plotting, and suggest an actual useful solution.

Comment: Note that you can also `set(gca,'ColorScale','log')`, instead of transforming the data like I suggested earlier: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#d126e69350